# SQL Server: How to efficiently return the combined result set of two slightly different queries

Tags: sql-server, union, common-table-expression

I've been playing with this for a while and while there are some "brute force" approaches that technically work, I feel like I'm missing something that would be more elegant (and efficient).

I have a single table that contains a history of events. For each event, there is a "source" and a "destination" (that is what I'm filtering on). I need to return to the top n rows ordered by the date (most recent first), first for a given destination from a particular source, and then for the same destination for any source other than the one used in the first query. For example, if the first query (matching both destination and source) returns n rows, I don't need any rows from the second query (matching the same destination and matching any *other* source), but if the first query returns less than n rows, I need the rest to be filled by the second query (assuming there are such rows).

Using UNION ALL does not work, because the individual queries can't be sorted separately, so I get a result set that contains the top n of "any" source for the given destination (if I could include the ORDER BY in each individual query, this would probably be a reasonable solution):

```
SELECT TOP (100) * FROM
(
SELECT TOP (100) Destin, Source, OtherData, Timestamp
FROM History
WHERE Destin = @Destin
AND Source = @source

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP (100) Destin, Source, OtherData, Timestamp
FROM History
WHERE Destin = @Destin
AND Source <> @source

ORDER BY Timestamp DESC
) AS SubQuery
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC
```

I've tried CTE as well, but haven't found anything better on that front. Any ideas on alternative approaches?

PS - The TOP (100) in the subqueries are an attempt at improving the performance, but I can't quite tell if SQL Server will automatically stop running the first (or second) subquery once it satisfies the TOP (100) in the outside query (which would be ideal).

Comment: Your sorting by timestamp. Does that still imply results come first from the first half of the union?

Comment: @shawnt00: Yes; the query shown doesn't quite work, because the limitation of the UNION ALL doesn't allow the individual queries to be sorted; the objective is to get the first 100 rows, most recent to oldest, "preferring" the ones that match both destination and source, but then "completing" the result set with the ones that match only the destination.

Comment: Well the sorting problem is handled by added an extra column to the results, say `1 as src` and `2 as src`. You can then sort on `src`. That doesn't address the performance considerations though which may be be handled by running the queries separately inside a proc and combining the results as necessary.

Comment: I hadn't yet looked at your queries very close. Of course Dan's answer is right on.

Comment: PS - Another way that this could work is to have two separate queries, where the second one (destin and not-source) is only run if the first one doesn't return enough rows to satisfy the "TOP" (the client would get one or two result sets, which can be handled). So this approach would also work, but I was thinking there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below uses a CASE expression to provide the desired sequence.  A clustered (or covering) index on destin will help optimize this query. This will perform a single seek.

```
SELECT TOP(100) Destin
      , Source
      , OtherData
      , Timestamp
      , CASE WHEN Source = @source THEN 1
             ELSE 2
        END AS seq
FROM    History
WHERE   Destin = @Destin
ORDER BY seq
      , Timestamp DESC;
```

**EDIT:**

Below is another technique that may perform better if the typical case is significantly more than 100 rows for the same destin.  A clustered/covering index on the ORDER BY columns like Aaron suggested will help performance here.  It's not as elegant as the CASE expression method and requires 2 seek operators, but is an option if performance is more important than maintainability.

```
WITH    same_source
          AS ( SELECT   Destin
                      , Source
                      , OtherData
                      , Timestamp
                      , 1 AS seq
                      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Destin, Source, Timestamp ) AS row_num
               FROM     dbo.History
               WHERE    Destin = @Destin
                        AND Source = @Source
             ) ,
        different_source
          AS ( SELECT   Destin
                      , Source
                      , OtherData
                      , Timestamp
                      , 2 AS seq
                      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Destin, Source, Timestamp ) AS row_num
               FROM     dbo.History
               WHERE    Destin = @Destin
                        AND Source <> @Source
             )
    SELECT TOP ( 100 )
            Destin
          , Source
          , OtherData
          , Timestamp
    FROM    ( SELECT    Destin
                      , Source
                      , OtherData
                      , Timestamp
                      , seq
              FROM      same_source
              WHERE     row_num <= 100
              UNION ALL
              SELECT    Destin
                      , Source
                      , OtherData
                      , Timestamp
                      , seq
              FROM      different_source
              WHERE     row_num <= 100
            ) AS test
    ORDER BY seq
          , Destin
          , Source
          , Timestamp;
```

Comment: Yep, that's pretty slick. Adding a TOP(n) to this looks like it will do the trick.  Destin is already the clustered index. I'll run some tests and look at the execution plan to make sure it's reasonably efficient (my concern is that this table contains millions of records). Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. It's doing a clustered index seek, which is fine, but there's still a pretty critical performance flaw: Let's say there are 10K rows with a particular destin, and 150 of those also have the source we care about. If TOP(n) is 100, the query would be much more efficient if it were searching for both destin and source (source is the second column in the clustered index). As-is, the result is the same, but SQL needs to search through most/all of the 10K records that match on destin. That's why I was originally approaching this with two separate queries.

Comment: @user640466 So make the index key `Destin, Source` and make sure it includes `OtherData` and `Timestamp` (<-- bad name for a column by the way). Then the order by will simply be placing the more important source first, and if there are more than 100, the others won't be looked at.

Comment: I ended up go with Dan's suggested CASE approach after including the timestamp in the index, which efficiently limits the maximum possible rows the query needs to consider.

Comment: @user640466, I added another method to my answer if the CASE approach isn't good enough.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Very interesting! I'll need to study this a bit and run a few tests to see how the two alternatives perform under different scenarios. Much appreciated!